# How to send HTML form to website for login, and download web page in c++ (using WinHTTP API)

Tags: c++, webforms, winhttp

> Hello! I am trying to log in to website and download an authorized
>   page. Currently, the website does not require any authentication
>   schema (I found out this from response headers). Name and password are
>   just verified by php script (I think so). Login page is
>   "http://example.com/dashboard/index.php". And the page I want to
>   download is "http://example.com/dashboard/dashboard.php". Chrome is
>   displaying dashboard page normally. But below cpp code is always
>   downloading the login page even after POST request. So what is wrong
>   in it? This html code is login page's form. Thanks in advance!

```
**************************************************************
<form name="login_form" action="" method="post" id="login_form"> 
                <div class="full mar2">
                    <div class="login-left">Username</div>
                    <div class="login-right">
                      <label>
                      <input type="text" name="username" value="" class="user"  />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full mar2">
                    <div class="login-left">Password</div>
                    <div class="login-right">
                      <label>
                      <input type="password" name="pswd" value="" class="user" />
                      </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full mar2">
                    <div class="login-left">&nbsp;</div>
                    <div class="login-right"><input type="submit" value="" name="sub_login" class="log-in" /></div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="sub_check" value="1" id="sub_check" />
                </form>
*******************************************************************



string GetHTMLTextFromWWW()
{
    HINTERNET hSess;
    hSess = WinHttpOpen(
        L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36",
        WINHTTP_ACCESS_TYPE_DEFAULT_PROXY,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_NAME,
        WINHTTP_NO_PROXY_BYPASS,
        0);
    if (!hSess) return "";

    HINTERNET hConn;
    hConn = WinHttpConnect(
        hSess,
        L"www.example.com",
        INTERNET_DEFAULT_PORT,
        0);
    if (!hConn)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSess);
        return "";
    }

    HINTERNET hReq;
    hReq = WinHttpOpenRequest(
        hConn,
        L"POST",
        L"/dashboard",
        NULL,
        WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
        WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
        WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH);
    if (!hReq)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConn);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSess);
        return "";
    }

    BOOL bRes;
    // I got the names from login page's html form
    char* data = "username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=";
    WinHttpSendRequest(
        hReq,
        L"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        -1,
        (LPVOID)data,
        strlen(data),
        strlen(data),
        0);

    bRes = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hReq, NULL);
    if (!bRes)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hReq);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConn);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSess);
        return "";
    }
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hReq);
    //...
    hReq = WinHttpOpenRequest(
        hConn,
        L"GET",
        L"/dashboard/dashboard.php",
        NULL,
        L"http://example.com/dashboard/index.php",
        WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
        WINHTTP_FLAG_REFRESH);
    if (!hReq)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConn);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSess);
        return "";
    }

    WinHttpSendRequest(
        hReq,
        WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS,
        0,
        WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA,
        0,
        0,
        0);

    bRes = WinHttpReceiveResponse(hReq, NULL);
    if (!bRes)
    {
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hReq);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hConn);
        WinHttpCloseHandle(hSess);
        return "";
    }

    DWORD cbSize(0);
    DWORD cbDownloaded;
    string Text = "";
    char *Buffer;
    do
    {
        cbSize = 0;
        if (WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hReq, &cbSize))
        {
            Buffer = new (nothrow) char[cbSize + 1];
            if (Buffer)
            {
                ZeroMemory(Buffer, cbSize + 1);
                if (WinHttpReadData(hReq, (LPVOID)Buffer, cbSize, &cbDownloaded))
                    Text += Buffer;
                delete [] Buffer;
            }
        }
    } while (cbSize > 0);

    WinHttpCloseHandle(hReq);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hConn);
    WinHttpCloseHandle(hSess);
    return Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is a simple authentification you have to do the following steps:

1. (as done by you) `hSess = WinHttpOpen(..);`
2. (as done by you) `hConn = WinHttpConnect(hSess, ..);`
3. `hReq = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConn, L"GET", ..);   // create get request`
4. Call `WinHttpSendRequest(hReq, WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 0, WINHTTP_NO_REQUEST_DATA, 0, 0, 0);` to inform HTTP server of your intentions
5. Receive the response by calling `WinHttpReceiveResponse(hReq, ..);`
6. Query the status of the request: `WinHttpQueryHeaders(hReq, WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER, ..);`
7. If status returned by `WinHttpQueryHeader(..)` is `HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND` stop since the HTTP server cannot provide the data.
8. If status returned by `WinHttpQueryHeader(..)` is `HTTP_STATUS_OK` retrieve the data using `WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hReq, ..)` and `WinHttpReadData(hReq, ..)` and continue with step 10.
9. If status returned by `WinHttpQueryHeader(..)` is `HTTP_STATUS_DENIED` call `WinHttpQueryAuthSchemes(hReq, &dwSupportedSchemes, &dwFirstScheme, &dwAuthTarget);` choose an authentification method and call (in the simplest way) `WinHttpSetCredentials(hReq, dwAuthTarget, dwFirstScheme, ..);` with your user name and password. After that being successfully done go back to step 4. (If you're coming here the second time your username and/or password is invalid)
10. Clean-up handles.

If you want I can provide the code for this but I have to extract itfrom a bigger junk of code which will take a while...

If the server uses cookies as authentification it's getting far more complicated since WinHttp is unable to handle cookies (or at least I was unable to make it handle cookies correctly). I've searched the internet from back to front and didn't find an answer but after long nights I managed to get a working implementation (propably only for my special case).

I hope this brief explanation helps. If you need my implementation of that I'll post it here.

**Edit 25/Oct/2014:**

Looks like I also missed a point of your question! My explanation from above is how to use an authentification scheme.

Here is a piece of code which I've extracted from my implementation which sends a POST request and reads the response. I matched it to your example but I didn't try nor compiled it:

```
BOOL bResult;
DWORD dwRead;
DWORD dwDownloaded;
DWORD dwTotalSize;
char *pBuffer;
DWORD dwSize;
DWORD dwStatusCode;
char buffer[1024 * 128];
DWORD len;

hRequest = WinHttpOpenRequest(hConnection,
                              L"POST",
                              L"http://example.com/dashboard/dashboard.php",
                              NULL,
                              WINHTTP_NO_REFERER,
                              WINHTTP_DEFAULT_ACCEPT_TYPES,
                              0);
if (hRequest != NULL)
{
    len = (DWORD)strlen("username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=");
    bResult = WinHttpSendRequest(hRequest,
                                 WINHTTP_NO_ADDITIONAL_HEADERS, 
                                 0, 
                                 "username=aan1982&pswd=admin1234&sub_check=1&sub_login=", 
                                 len,
                                 len, 
                                 0);
    if (bResult != FALSE)
    {
        if (WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL) != FALSE)
        {
            dwSize = sizeof(dwStatusCode);
            bResult = WinHttpQueryHeaders(hRequest, 
                                          WINHTTP_QUERY_STATUS_CODE | WINHTTP_QUERY_FLAG_NUMBER,
                                          NULL, 
                                          &dwStatusCode, 
                                          &dwSize, 
                                          NULL);
            if (bResult != FALSE)
            {
                switch (dwStatusCode)
                {
                case HTTP_STATUS_OK:
                    pBuffer = buffer;
                    dwTotalSize = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        dwSize = 0;
                        if (WinHttpQueryDataAvailable(hRequest, &dwSize) != FALSE)
                        {
                            dwRead = dwSize;
                            if (dwRead > sizeof(buffer))
                                dwRead = sizeof(buffer);

                            bResult = WinHttpReadData(hRequest,
                                                      pBuffer,
                                                      dwRead,
                                                      &dwDownloaded);
                            if (bResult == FALSE)
                            {
                                printf("Failed to read data (error: %d)\n", GetLastError());
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                pBuffer += dwDownloaded;
                                dwTotalSize += dwDownloaded;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    while (dwSize > 0);

                    /*
                    **  TODO:
                    **  Write buffer to file or process it...
                    */
                    break; /* HTTP_STATUS_OK */

                case HTTP_STATUS_DENIED:
                    printf("access denied!\n");
                    break; /* HTTP_STATUS_DENIED */

                case HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND:
                    printf("file not found\n");
                    break; /* HTTP_STATUS_NOT_FOUND */

                default:
                    printf("WinHttpQueryHeaders(..): dwStatusCode=%d\n", dwStatusCode);
                    break; /* default */
                } /* switch (dwStatusCode) */
            }
            else /* if (bResult != FALSE) */
            {
                printf("WinHttpQueryHeaders(..) failed (error: %d)\n", GetLastError());
            }
        }
        else /* if (WinHttpReceiveResponse(hRequest, NULL) != FALSE) */
        {
            printf("WinHttpReceiveResponse(..) failed (error: %d)\n", GetLastError());
        }
    }
    else /* if (bResult != FALSE) */
    {
        printf("Failed to send request (error: %d)\n", GetLastError());
    }
}
else /* if (http->hRequest != NULL) */
{
    printf("Failed to open request (error: %d)\n", GetLastError());
}
```

Additionally I recommend the use of HttpFox (a FireFox addin). With that tool you can monitor HTTP requests done by FireFox. This is useful to get an idea what's going on and this is a good place to start to implement it.

Let me know if it worked...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The status code is always 200, that is, HTTP_STATUS_OK. Yes, please can you post it? I would like to have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you for your post. Your code is looking good. But it also downloads the login page. But the problem is solved. I just removed "www" from the server's name, and it worked. If to tell the truth, I didn't know there was a difference between "www.example.com" and "example.com".